# Use of threading inside onclick view and switch case

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, threadpool

I am new to android development , my app is ready but on some devices it lags when opening the navigation drawer and somethings on onclick event.I tried to use threads so that each event occurs on new thread but still i see lag please help me with this.

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity implements OnClickListener {
private Button scanBtn,scanBtn2,scanBtn3;
Animation animTranslate,animAlpha;
LinearLayout lv;
Handler handler;
String[] permissions;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    permissions = new String[3];
    permissions[0] = Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
    permissions[1] = Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
    permissions[2]=Manifest.permission.CAMERA;
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this,
            permissions,
            5
    );



    scanBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.scanner);
    scanBtn2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.scanner2);
    scanBtn3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.scanner3);

    lv=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);


    animTranslate=  AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this,R.anim.anim_translate);
       animAlpha=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this,R.anim.anim_alpha);

            scanBtn.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);       

            scanBtn2.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);         

            scanBtn3.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);

 }     
 public void onClick(View v){
    if(v.getId()==R.id.scanner){
        v.startAnimation(animTranslate);
        lv.startAnimation(animAlpha);
        final IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
         scanIntegrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE_TYPES);
        scanIntegrator.setPrompt(" ");
        scanIntegrator.setCameraId(0);
        scanIntegrator.setBeepEnabled(true);
        scanIntegrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false);
        handler=new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
            }
        },500);
    }else if(v.getId()==R.id.scanner2){
        v.startAnimation(animTranslate);
        lv.startAnimation(animAlpha);
        final IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator2=new  IntentIntegrator(this);
         scanIntegrator2.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.ONE_D_CODE_TYPES);
        scanIntegrator2.setPrompt(" ");
        scanIntegrator2.setCameraId(0);
        scanIntegrator2.setBeepEnabled(true);
        scanIntegrator2.setBarcodeImageEnabled(true);
        handler=new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                scanIntegrator2.initiateScan();
            }
        },500);
    }else if(v.getId()==R.id.scanner3){
        v.startAnimation(animTranslate);
        lv.startAnimation(animAlpha);
        final Intent intent=new  Intent(this,GenerateQRCodeActivity.class);
        handler=new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                startActivity(intent);                     overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right,R.anim.slide_out_left);

            }
        },500);
    }
 }

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    IntentResult scanningResult =  IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    if (scanningResult != null) {
        String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
        String scanFormat = scanningResult.getFormatName();
        Intent intent1=new Intent(this,ResultActivity.class);
        intent1.putExtra("con",scanContent);
        if(scanContent != null && scanFormat != null) {
            startActivity(intent1);
        }

    }
    else{
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
 }


@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent e) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
        // your action...

        if (!mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)) {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
        }
        else{
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        }
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, e);
 }

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)){
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }
    else{
        finish();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: remove the thread for click listeners. you don't need a thread here. you need a thread when you are doing some background work

Comment: Ok i removed the threads from onclick event...but i can still see lag can u recommend me something if u want i can post baseactivity.java too

Comment: Post your updated code.

Comment: i edited my updated code

Comment: I learnt that asynctask can help me with my problem..but i dont know how to and where to implement it my code ...